# Wordpress (Woocommerce) running multiple shortcodes gives unexpected products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop page where I want to display a top 5, sale products etc.

I'm running the following codes one after another:

```
[products ids="5597, 343, 8095, 15784, 54401" columns="5"]
[products category="neu-im-shop" columns="5" limit="5" orderby="date" order="desc"]
[products on_sale="true" columns="5" limit="5" orderby="modified" order="desc"]
```

using the do_shortcode function in PHP.

The first shortcode always gives the same expected output. The other only give the correct output when I run them first.

Anybode know what's going on there?

I tried cleanup functions but they seem to be called from woocommerce anyway.

Comment: Your function is overriding to each other.

Comment: So how would I go about not overriding them?